# How to Get Shape Name

Tags: shapefile, dotspatial

Using DotSpatial, if I open a Shapefile as an `IFeatureSet`, I can see a collection of shapes within the `FeatureSet` and these shapes have collections of attributes.  But I can't see an obvious way of finding the name associated to the shape?

For example, if I have the following code:

```
var featureSet = Shapefile.Open("../../Ecuador/map.shp");

var rowCount = featureSet.NumRows();

for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
{
    var shape = featureSet.GetShape(i, true);
    var geometry = shape.ToGeometry();
}
```

If I debug into this code by putting a breakpoint on the `Shape` object I can see a collections of attributes.  In the example I'm using, each shape has 12 attributes.  I can see that one of these attributes is what I would consider to be the name of the shape (in this example I'm looking at the provinces of Ecuador), but I have no idea how to reliably pair which one of these attributes would be the shape name, in this case the name of the province.

**Edit**

Here is an example of the available attributes I can see for the first shape:

[image: Image of available shape attributes]

From a quick look, I'd say that the attribute at index 4 was the one I need, but how do I find this out programmatically?

**Further Edit**

It looks as though, through further poking about in the data that the labels for the attributes might be the DataTable Column names in the `IFeatureSet`:

[image: Image of data table column values]

Although... which of these would I pick programmatically if I wanted to import these shapes?  Is the only way to allow the person doing the import to manually pick the correct one?

Comment: Are you looking for a unique identifier to associate with each shape?  It's possible that some columns in the Attribute Table are not unique.  Usually users choose a column for cartographic reasons, e.g. a column may contain labels, not necessarily unique, that the user wishes to display on the map.  The FID in DotSpatial is unique.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm looking for the name of the shape.  In my example I'm loading in shape data (polygons) for the provinces of Ecuador.  In KML there would be a 'Name' element for each feature, where I would expect to find the name of each province.  I think since I've rethought this and looked at other formats like GeoJSON, I've come to the conclusion that with Shapefile the data is there, but it's found in an attribute collection in the DBF data.  From what I've found out, it looks like you would need to then know that the province name is stored in attribute 4.

Comment: The shape file's DBF does not necessarily have a name attribute.  KML includes cartographic elements but shape files do not

Comment: Cheers, I ended up going with a solution similar to the Google Earth solution.  I show the user a table with columns of attribute sets and let the user pick which one represents the naming data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a page called [Importing Geographic Information Systems (GIS) data in Google Earth](http://www.google.com/earth/outreach/tutorials/importgis.html).

The process to import from a shapefile shows a screenshot where the user is asked to select the attribute that contains the names for the shapes, from a table of available attributes.

[image: Image showing the selecting of the name field]

It looks as though the task of attaching names to features is handled manually by the user.